# 3D printer simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

i am trying to build something like a primitive 3D printer in blender using fluid dynamics . I am having real problems to control the fluid dynamics . 
i was looking for something like this as a start but better if the fluid is a little less viscous when reaching the print bed ...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Se4v-QRWtYA

the idea is to build a fun low polly structure then actually print the results . 
any pointers would be great thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A 3D printer doesn't really push out fluids... Fluid dynamics is the wrong way to approach it I would say.

I would personally try to simulate it more using a particle system replicating small spheroids or cubes, where the particles have 0 motion and randomness out of the nozzle, and become children of the bed plate object to move along with the bed plate in your motion system.

I've designed the chassis of my printer with Blender and am looking at doing something similar for video demo purposes, will post an update if you still need help with that when I get over the hurdles I'm facing.